# How to import rpc information without importing .env file or hardcoding on frontend?

Tags: blockchain, web3js

I'm going to import rpc url to connect to blockchain in web3 part of frontend.
But my client doesn't allow this.
`let RPC_METADATA = process.env["RPC_METADATA"];`
He considered environment configuration to be the same as hardcoding.
There should be no direct reference to a URL for the backend in the project at all.
How can I use rpc url without importing .env file or hardcoding on frontend?

I tried using .env file and hardcoding like this.
`let rpc = process.env['rpc_info']`
`let rpc = 'https://ourchain_rpc_url'`

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to hide the actual target URL (in your case RPC; I'm assuming the URL contains some API key or other sensitive information) is to hide it behind a proxy service.

Your frontend queries a backend proxy service. This proxy service doesn't contain any sensitive information in its URL, queries the target RPC, and then returns the response from the RPC back to the frontend.

---

You can set up the proxy service's CORS headers to accept requests only from the frontend and reject all other requests.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://your_frontend_domain
```

Docs:

- General info on CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
- Allow origin header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin